# Google Analytics Reporting API Failed to get Unique Page Views

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics Reporting API v4 to get my analytics data, I am following the same steps, where creating Views and adding my site as well, but it is not working, I have my subdomain site like abcd.xyz.com

Nd I am hitting site by different valid IP addresses yet it is not giving any results to show in dashboard.

Is there anything to keep on my homepage or site so that Google Analytics knows that this website has been HIT?

I have heard about gTag but still I kept at home page but failed to achieven any results:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  //gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'page_title' : 'homepage',
  'page_path': '/'
});
</script>
```

My Google Reporting API Code where I am fetching the data:

```
$VIEW_ID = "viewid";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

I even looked into my google analytics dashboard but failed to get results.

Is something missing with the flow.

Comment: Does `even looked into my google analytics dashboard but failed to get results` mean you're not seeing any traffic in the Google Analytics reports?

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to see pageviews for your main site and the subdomain (unless that's all the same)? If so, you will need to install the GTAG on both domains in order to collect data.

When you look at your views in Google Analytics, you should see data unless one of the following is taking place:

- You haven't installed the GTAG to collect data
- You have very little or no traffic coming to your site
- You have applied a filter correctly or incorrectly that's blocking traffic or segments of traffic from your view.

Also, when you pull data, are you using Google App Script to access the Reporting API? If so, you could try creating your request a little different. I've put together some code that I use all of the time that gives me no issues. Feel free to repurpose for your needs:

https://github.com/jessfeliciano/aggregateGoogleAnalyticsReporting/blob/master/objectQueryWithFilter.js

Next steps for you I would say the following:

- Confirm pageviews are pushing to the GA property either by looking at network calls, Google Tag Assistant or viewing yourself in the Real Time reports in GA
- Once you've confirmed data is collecting, make sure the time frame you are viewing data for has actual data collected
- If data is collecting for the time frame you're looking at you might have an issue with your report request - feel free to look at the documentation I provided above for assistance.

If you send me a link to your website, I'm more than happy to look into this further for you, cheers!